# BeautifulSoup : selecting specific stanzas and classes

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am cooking some BeautifulSoup and want to extract some text that is inside the **p** stanza 
I am able to rip out the script and the style, but I can't find out how to discern between classes.

```
<html>
...
<script>...</script>
<style>...</style>
...
<p class="bad">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="text">consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
<p class="text">sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>
..
</html>
```

and this is my python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
import re
import html5lib
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

li = "http://www.example.com/index.html"
htm = urllib.request.urlopen(li).read().decode("utf8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htm, "html5lib")

## kick out scripts and styles
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()

## get text
text = soup.get_text()
```

print(text) will output this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore

QUESTION: how can I extract just the text inside the p stanza with **class="text"** , so practically just :

> consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore

Comment: it say: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text', but I got the message. I must read select

Comment: Sorry, I meant `soup.select_one('.text').text`, the `select()` method returns result set...

Comment: @AndrejKesely and if I have more then one class text ? is there a way to concatenate all results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join multiple selected string you can use `str.join` with list comprehension.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<html>

<p class="text">This is good text</p>
<p class="bad">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="text">consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
<p class="bad">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = '\n'.join(txt.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n') for txt in soup.select('.text'))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
This is good text
consetetur sadipscing elitr
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
soup.find_all("p", class_= "text")
```

That will return you the p by the class "text"
and if you have more then one you can iter over them

```
for i in soup.find_all("p", class_= "text"):
    print(i.text)
```

will return in your case

```
consetetur sadipscing elitr
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
```

or if you want it in the same line

```
print(*[i.text for i in soup.find_all("p", class_= "text")])
```

Output

```
consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
```